# Did I import inetOrgPerson schema correctly for OpenLDAP on Alpine Linux?

Tags: linux, ldap, schema, openldap, alpine-linux

I'm trying to import a user into OpenLDAP on Alpine Linux. Here's the LDIF that I named searchUser.ldif:

```
# Search account
dn: uid=search,dc=home
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: search
sn: search
uid: search
```

The command I used to import it is:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=home" -w supersecret -f searchUser.ldif
```

The error I get is:

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21) additional info: objectClass: value #2 invalid per syntax
```

My understanding of this is the objectClasses are numbered, starting with 0, and that #2 indicates the problem is with inetOrgPerson.

I've done this successfully using OpenLDAP on Raspberry Pi OS (debian). However, I get the feeling the Debian package automates some configuration steps that the Alpine package does not. One of those steps I think Debian does during the package install is to import inetOrgPerson schema.

I've tried to do the schema import manually. Here are the steps I took prior to trying the LDIF import...

I scripted my install of OpenLDAP on Alpine, like so:

```
export DOMAIN="dc=home"
 
echo "Installing packages..."
apk add openldap openldap-back-mdb openldap-clients
 
echo "Configuring for v2.3+ style slapd.d config directory..."
install -m 755 -o ldap -g ldap -d /etc/openldap/slapd.d
sed -i~ \
  -e 's/^cfgfile=/#cfgfile=/' \
  -e 's/^#cfgdir=.*/cfgdir=\"\/etc\/openldap\/slapd.d\"/' \
  /etc/conf.d/slapd
rm /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
 
echo "Customizing for domain: ${DOMAIN}..."
sed -i~ \
  -e 's/\.la$/.so/' \
  -e "s/dc=my-domain,dc=com/${DOMAIN}/" /etc/openldap/slapd.ldif
 
echo "Importing configuration..."
slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -l /etc/openldap/slapd.ldif
chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d/*
 
echo "Configuring slapd service..."
install -m 755 -o ldap -g ldap -d /var/lib/openldap/run
service slapd start
rc-update add slapd
```

The slapd service started and I could connect to it with command-line tools and from a client over port 389. So far, so good.

The next thing I did was to import schema for cosine and inetOrgPerson. I believe the Debian package did this automatically, because I don't recall having to do this previously.

Here's what I did on Alpine to import the schema:

```
slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -l /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif
slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -l /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

There were no errors.

I then created an organization using the command `ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=home" -w secret -f org.ldif` and this LDIF as org.ldif:

```
dn: dc=home
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: Home
dc: home

dn: cn=Manager,dc=home
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager
```

This too was successful.

I can also create organizational units with this LDIF:

```
# Organizational unit for users
dn: ou=People,dc=home
changetype: add
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

# Organizational unit for groups.
dn: ou=Groups,dc=home
changetype: add
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Groups
```

So I think my server is okay, but I may have done something wrong with the inetOrgPerson schema import that's causing the Invalid syntax (21) error.

Is the way I'm importing the inetOrgPerson schema correct? Is there a way to verify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem was due to incorrect ownership for the new files in the /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema directory. Once I fixed that, I was able to import the search user.

Because I ran the `slapd` commands as the root user, the resulting schema config files were owned by root. I discovered this when I restarted the slapd service and it failed with this error in /var/log/messages:

```
ldif_read_file: Permission denied for "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={1}cosine.ldif"
```

The solution was to change ownership on the files. This is the correct ownership:

```
alpine:/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema# ls -l
total 32
-rw-------    1 ldap     ldap         15575 May  5 12:43 cn={0}core.ldif
-rw-------    1 ldap     ldap         11361 May  5 14:53 cn={1}cosine.ldif
-rw-------    1 ldap     ldap          2855 May  5 14:53 cn={2}inetorgperson.ldif
```

So the answer to this question is...

1. Yes, importing with `slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -l /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif` worked fine, but the command should have been run as the `ldap` user so the ownership is correct. (Or run as root and change ownership after.)
2. One way to verify the schema is to look inside the /etc/openldap/slapd.d directory. Specifically, /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema shows evidence of the schema I added.

Even with the potential for incorrect file ownership, I see this as a much easier way to add schema than some of the other tutorials I've found that involve creating and editing a temporary slapd.conf file.